# Sorting a list of dictionaries that contains a list as a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have this list of dictionaries which have a list as the value:

```
>>> lod
[{'A': ['100', '200', '300', 600]}, {'B': ['1000', '2000', '3000', 6000]}, {'C': ['1', '2', '3', 6]}]
```

and basically, I need to sort this list based on the last item in every dictionary's list.

So I used sorted() but it didn't work as expected:

```
>>> sorted(lod, key= lambda x: lod[0][''.join(list(lod[0].keys()))][3])

[{'A': ['100', '200', '300', 600]}, {'B': ['1000', '2000', '3000', 6000]}, {'C': ['1', '2', '3', 6]}]
```

What do you think is the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it correct that every last element of your lists is an int but the previous elements are strings? This data might need some preprocessing...

Comment: you need to use `map` to convert your list items to `int` first

Comment: @timgeb yes, this is the structure of the list, 3 strings followed by an integer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this is not how the `key` parameter works. It should be a function that's used like this in the sorting algorithm:

```
if key(a) < key(b):
    # sort this way
```

So, it needs to return the value you want to be compared:

```
sorted(lod, key=lambda elem: next(iter(elem.values()))[-1])
```

Comment: @timgeb, that's only because one can't index `dict_values` objects for some reason (I think Python 3.7 should remove this restriction since dicts are now ordered; maybe it already did - I'm on Python 3.6 right now), but can iterate over them.

Comment: yes, that's why I casted the values to a tuple before indexing

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that all your dicts have exactly one (key, value) pair and that the last element of the value-list is an integer, the following solution should fit your criteria.

```
>>> l = [{'A': ['100', '200', '300', 600]}, {'B': ['1000', '2000', '3000', 6000]}, {'C': ['1', '2', '3', 6]}]
>>> 
>>> criterion = lambda dict_: tuple(dict_.values())[0][-1]
>>> sorted(l, key=criterion)
>>> 
[{'C': ['1', '2', '3', 6]},
 {'A': ['100', '200', '300', 600]},
 {'B': ['1000', '2000', '3000', 6000]}]
```

`tuple(dict_.values())` constructs a one-element tuple of the values for each inner dict, `[0]` gets the list out of that tuple and `[-1]` gets the last element of that list as the sorting-criterion.

Comment: PEP-something recommends you defined named functions explicitly instead of assigning labels to `lambda` functions.

Comment: @jpp yes, and `l` is a bad variable name. It's a demo code snippet. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(lod, key=lambda d: list(d.values())[0][-1])
```

will do it. Explanation: `list(d.values())[0]` will return the only value from your dictionary, `[-1]` will return last item of it (int value used for sorting)